# Excel if the cell value from columns 1 and 2 match, insert a value from cell 2's row into another cell of cell 1's row

Tags: excel-formula

I need to find the row X in SHEET2 which contains the same value in its coulmn A (there is one such value in the entire Column A) that matches Column C value of my current cell on SHEET1 and then put the value from SHEET2 row X's column D into the current cell where I am entering the formula you hopefully provide to me :)))

I tried this:

```
="SHEET2!D"& MATCH('SHEET1!C16,SHEET2!A:A,0)
```

instead of entering the value it inserts:

```
DBW!D110
```

So it does find the correct row (#110 in this case) and DBW!D110 is the correct cell, how do I get its value (an not its cell #)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SHEET 1
  A   B  C  D
1 1   2  8  =VLOOKUP(C1,SHEET2!A:A,4,FALSE)
2 10  6  4  =VLOOKUP(C2,SHEET2!A:A,4,FALSE)
3 15  5  11 =VLOOKUP(C3,SHEET2!A:A,4,FALSE)

SHEET 2
  A  B  C
1 4  5  23 
2 8  7  45
3 11 12 16
```

This requires that Sheet2 column is Alpha sorted to work properly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This returs #N/A
What does this mean?

Comment: On Microsoft site I read: "If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first column of table_array, VLOOKUP returns the #N/A error value." but the values I have it C colum are copied from SHEET2!A cells so there is an identical value SHEET2!A:A that matches each colum C cell.

Answer (score 0):

once you have the cell reference, you can view its value using `INDIRECT`, so your formula would change from

```
="SHEET2!D"& MATCH('SHEET1!C16,SHEET2!A:A,0)
```

to

```
=INDIRECT("SHEET2!D"& MATCH('SHEET1!C16,SHEET2!A:A,0))
```